# How can I classify my data for K-Means Clustering

Tags: matlab

A proof of concept prototype I have to do for my final year project is to implement **K-Means Clustering** on a big data set and display the results on a graph. I only know object-oriented languages like Java and C# and decided to give MATLAB a try. I notice that with a functional language the approach to solving problems is very different, so I would like some insight on a few things if possible.

Suppose I have the following data set:

**raw_data**

```
400.39  513.29  499.99  466.62  396.67
234.78  231.92  215.82  203.93  290.43
15.07   14.08   12.27   13.21   13.15
334.02  328.79  272.2   306.99  347.79
49.88   52.2    66.35   47.69   47.86
732.88  744.62  687.53  699.63  694.98
```

And I picked row 2 and 4 to be the 2 centroids:

**centroids**

```
234.78  231.92  215.82  203.93  290.43    % Centroid 1
334.02  328.79  272.2   306.99  347.79    % Centroid 2
```

I want to now compute the euclidean distances of each point to each centroid, then assign each point to it's closest centroid and display this on a graph. Let's say I want I want to classify the centroids as blue and green. How can I do this in MATLAB? If this was Java I would initialise each row as an object and add to separate ArrayLists (representing the clusters).

If rows 1, 2 and 3 all belong to the first centroid / cluster, and rows 4, 5 and 6 belong to the second centroid / cluster - how can I classify these to display them as blue or green points on a graph? I am new to MATLAB and really curious about this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

(To begin with, Matlab has a flexible distance measuring function, `pdist2` and also `kmeans` implementation, but I'm assuming that you want to build your code from scratch).

In Matlab, you try to implement everything as matrix algebra, without loops over elements.

In your case, if R is the raw_data matrix and C is the centroids matrix,
you can shift the dimension that represents centroid number to the 3rd place by
`permC=permute(C,[3 2 1])`; Then the `bsxfun` function allows you to subtract C from R while expanding R's third dimension as necessary: `D=bsxfun(@minus,R,permC)`. Element-wise square followed by summation across columns `SqD=sum(D.^2,2)` will give you the squared distances of each observation from each centroid. Performing all these operations within a single statement and shifting the third (centroid) dimension back to the 2nd place will look like this:

```
SqD=permute(sum(bsxfun(@minus,R,permute(C,[3 2 1])).^2,2),[1 3 2])
```

Picking the centroid of minimal distance is now straightforward: `[minDist,minCentroid]=min(SqD,[],2)`

If this looks complex, I recommend inspecting the product of each sub-step and reading the help of each command.